# Render prop in lists keeps remounting

Tags: reactjs

I have a `List` component that accepts a `render` prop. The `render` function then gets passed a Component. Something like this:

```
function List({ render, items }) {
  return (
    <ul>
      {items.map(() => {
        return render('li');
      })}
    </ul>
  );
}

<List items={[...]} render={(Wrapper) => {
    return <Wrapper>...</Wrapper>
}}
```

While above example works, if I want to pass a Component to the `render` function as an inline function (so I can for example pass a slightly different component based on the item index) — the `rendered` component keeps "remounting".

```
function List({ render, items }) {
  const [number, setNumber] = useState(null);
  return (
    <ul>
      {items.map((item, index) => {
        return render(({...props}) => {
          return <TestListItem onClick={() => {
            // bit of logic that's different for each item
            setNumber(index)
          }} {...props}/>
        });
      })}
    </ul>
  );
}

function TestListItem ({...props) {
  useEffect(() => {
    // function that only runs when Test List gets mounted
    console.log('first render');
  }, [])
  return <li {...props} />
}

<List items={[...]} render={(Wrapper) => {
  return <Wrapper>...</Wrapper>
}}
```

This is evidenced by `console.log('first render')` being executed every time `onClick={() => { setNumber(index) }}` happens.

I understand this happens because I'm passing an inline function. But I'm not sure how to do this without passing an inline function but still being able to pass props that are specific to the item index. How do I do this using render props - or maybe even using another solution?

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question. I fixed this by passing **children** (`<TestListItem/>`) to the `render` function, instead of **components/elements** (`() => <TestListItem/>`).